# Set Div Height equal to Page height using JavaScript / AngularJS / CSS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

### AngularJS Code:

```
angular.module("app").config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function (cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        //  cfpLoadingBarProvider.parentSelector = '#loading-bar-container';
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div class="backgroundHide"><div class="centerLoad"><img  src="img/large-spinner.gif" /></div></div>';
    }]);
```

### CSS Code:

```
.backgroundHide{
background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
opacity: 0.8;
z-index: 100000000;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
top:100px;
position:absolute;

}
```

Comment: ...and the question is?...

Comment: I want to know When We click any button, then a div appears above form with processing image, but this does not cover whole page. So how to make height dynamic of div to cover whole page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.backgroundHide{
background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
opacity: 0.8;
z-index: 100000000;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
top:100px;
position:fixed;

}
```

Comment: Yes it might, not necessarily the best way though, as `position: fixed`, when used like that, can give unexpected issue, particular on mobiles/tablets. If you can provide, within your question, the CSS for `centerLoad` and the spinner `img` a long with the rendered html, we most likely would be able to suggest a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 .backgroundHide{
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 100000000;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are setting the height of your `backgroundHide` to 100% which means that it will take 100% of the **parent's element** height.

If you want to take 100% of the **viewport** height you should use `vh`

```
.backgroundHide{
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 100000000;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    top:100px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the result ? And the full html ? not only the div backgroundHide

Comment: angular.module("app").config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function (cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div class="backgroundHide"><div class="centerLoad"><img  src="img/large-spinner.gif" /></div></div>';
    }]);

Comment: This is not your HTML page

Comment: Actually, This div appears only on click any button and shows a progressing image withing it. This does not whole page, only half page. So I want to cover whole page by this div.

Comment: This is AngularJS SPA. Only above code is responsible for it.

Comment: I need to see the final HTML. The backgroundHide is maybe blocker or overriden by other element

Answer (score 0):

Covers viewport

```
.backgroundHide{
    background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 100000000;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100vw;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

pageHeight will give you the height of the viewport, now you can assign that height to the div that actually you want.

```
  var pageHeight = $(window).height();
    $('div').css('hieght',);
```